# When is it considered a good time to delete your local / remote feature branches?

Tags: branching-and-merging, tortoisegit

I now have several branches that have all been **merged** into the master branch:

[image: Ref Browser]

I have yet to create a **tag** and officially release this edition.

So when is the best time to remove your merged branches? I noticed in **TortoiseGit** that when you merge the branch there is a check box for **Delete Branch**.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why the vote to close? Ho hum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your workflow. But generally after merge.

A common workflow is:

- merge to `develop` (if you have a build server, see that the build is ok)
- delete local branch and the tracking remote

Comment: Thanks. When you delete branches, does it affect how the "log" looks. You know, when you see branches that were created and merged. Does that master branch retain things visually? Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @AndrewTruckle you know that graph that most git tools will show you of branches? that is a really useful way to think about this (ie this http://gitup.co/images/snapshots.gif) if you delete your branch before it was merged (see it on the gif linked)  into another branch then any commit that you have done won't be linked to anything so it will be lost. if you do have it merged then it won't be.